# Can we connect a web application to ONA ODK forms?

Tags: opendata, odk, odk-xform

Can we connect a web application to ONA ODK forms ?

I need to replace a system where employees goes to field, collect information, and then sync to database when they come back.

What we need is to find a solution, by creating odk surveys, let the employee collect data, and then sync directly to ona and mysql database. And I need to give them the ability to read and edit data directly form the forms into database.

I know the idea is a little bit strange.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask this question in [ODK Community](https://forum.opendatakit.org/) and as you want a solution for sending data that can be done by the cloud-based server like google cloud and for editing data. It's not a good practice to edit data in a raw dataset. You can download data from the server and then you can make a change in your computer. 
Even if you want to give them access to the server so they can log-in and make a change on the server, you can create a username and password so they can update their records.